# Jquery: How to add repeat data in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add repeat data post to ajax,

but, I don't know where a problem,

Please help me, very thank you~!

If input class is employ click,so add active class.

and click finish_sumbit get input employ.active.val() my console.log

but repeat is trouble~!

this is my HTML

```
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="bruce">
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="peter">
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="abcd">
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="efgh">

<a href="#" class="finish_sumbit">完了</a>
```

this is my Javascript

```
$('.employ').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(".finish_sumbit").click(function(){
 var rows = $('.employ.active');
 var employ = $('.employ.active').val();
 for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
 {
     var data = {'employ':employ[i],'test_id':'1'};
 }
 console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "business_a",
    async:false,
    data: {bruce:data,_token:token},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (data) {
      alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to create an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code. The `.val()` will return only the value of the first element in the calling set so `employ` will always be a single value. Also in the loop you are always overriding the value of `data`

Since you can have multiple object, `data` should be an array

```js
$('.employ').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(".finish_sumbit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('.employ.active').map(function() {
    return {
      'employ': this.value,
      'test_id': '1'
    }
  }).get();

  console.log(data);
  $('pre').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="bruce">
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="peter">
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="abcd">
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="efgh">

<a href="#" class="finish_sumbit">完了</a>
<br />
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: thank you~! 
I get employ data is use data[1][employ] << this is ok?

Answer (score 0):

In your for cycle, you are initializing new data variable every loop! Put var data; on the start of script, in for cycle will be without var

Use jQuery extend. 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/